Behaviour differences between cburst and burst tc-htb linux
I've deployed an tc-htb in order to guarantee different bitrates to different flows. However, for traffic that belongs to class 1:10, I also want to allow some burst.
I've read the tc-htb documentation to see the difference between burst and cburst, but I don't know why the burst does not do anything and it only works the cburst.
The configuration that I'm using is:
tc qdisc add dev ifb0 root handle 1: htb default 12 
tc class add dev ifb0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbit ceil 100mbit 
tc class add dev ifb0 parent 1:1 classid 1:2 htb rate 40mbit ceil 40mbit 
tc class add dev ifb0 parent 1:1 classid 1:3 htb rate 20mbit ceil 100mbit
tc class add dev ifb0 parent 1:2 classid 1:10 htb rate 30mbit ceil 30mbit burst 100K {cburst 100K}
tc class add dev ifb0 parent 1:2 classid 1:11 htb rate 8bit ceil 40mbit 
tc class add dev ifb0 parent 1:1 classid 1:12 htb rate 8bit ceil 100mbit

[I also defined some filters in order to assign each flow to a class]
